# LWP authentication - Negotiate

Tags: perl, authentication

I have tried many solutions but still no answer.
I am trying to access a xml webpage from a server that uses authentication.
it's either kerberos or NTLM but I am having trouble unserstanding which one ( I tried both of them .. )
I used LWP but I keep getting 401 unauthorized error.

I used wireshark in order to view the difference between the browser header and the header my script creates and they are not the same.
the credentials appear in different places.

I have tried many ways and this is my current try :

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib";
use File::Basename;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Authen::NTLM;
#use HTML::TableExtract;
use HTML::Form;
use HTML::Template;
#use MIME::Entity;

my $Options = {
    user => "Citrix",
    host => "<ip>",
    password => "Rel0aded1",
    domain => "lyncent.com",
    timeout => 30,
    protocol => "http",
    AuthMethod => "Negotiate",
    BrowserAgent => "MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0",
    RequestMethod => "GET",
    DataDir => "/tmp",
};
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent=>'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)',
    keep_alive=>'1'
);
my $url = "http://<ip>/Citrix/Monitor/OData/v1/Methods/";
ntlm_domain($Options->{'domain'});
ntlm_user($Options->{'user'});
ntlm_password($Options->{'password'});

my $Authorization = Authen::NTLM::ntlm();

my $header = HTTP::Headers->new(
    Content_Type => 'text/html',
    'WWW-Authenticate' => $Options->{'AuthMethod'}
);

$header->header('Authorization' => "NTLM $Authorization");
my $request = HTTP::Request->new($Options->{'RequestMethod'} => $url, $header);
my $res = $browser->request( $request );


# Second stage of authentication
print Dumper $res;
print $res->request->as_string();
my $Challenge = $res->header('WWW-Authenticate');
$Challenge =~ s/^NTLM //g;
$browser->credentials('192.168.100.41:80', 'LYNCENT', "lyncent.com\\Citrix", 'Rel0aded1');
ntlm_domain($Options->{'domain'});
ntlm_user($Options->{'user'});
ntlm_password($Options->{'password'});
#$Authorization = Authen::NTLM::ntlm($Challenge);
$Authorization = Authen::NTLM::ntlm(
    host     => $Options->{'host'},
    user     => $Options->{'user'},
    domain   => $Options->{'domain'},
    password => $Options->{'password'},
    version  => 1,
);
$Authorization -> challenge($Challenge);
$header->header('Authorization' => "NTLM $Authorization");
$header->header('User' => $Options->{'user'});
$header->header('Password' => $Options->{'password'});
$header->header('Domain' => $Options->{'domain'});

$request = HTTP::Request->new($Options->{'RequestMethod'} => $url, $header);

$res = $browser->request($request);
print Dumper $res;
print $res->request->as_string();
#
# ntlm needs to be resetted after second stage 
#
ntlm_reset();

if($res->is_success) {
    print "$Options->{'DataDir'}/test_url" .  $res->content;
}
else {
    print  "not working:".  $res->code ." and " . $res->status_line ."\n";
}

}
```

this is the headers from my prints:

GET http:link
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB7IAAAYABgAgAAAACwALACYAAABDaXRyaXhseW5jZW50LmNvbQ==
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Content-Type: text/html

GET http:'link'
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAEAAAAAYABgAWAAAAAAAAAAwAAAADAAMAHAAAAAMAAwAfAAAAAAAAABIAAAAAAAAAMzMtTg4NEGeGv0QgPZbp9YSENlLFzZSqlvbV1ohNAOQV0uJR+lLaaFCEhvYCPPNyUMAaQB0AHIA
EMAaQB0AHIAaQB4AA==
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
Content-Type: text/html
Domain: lyncent.com
Password: Rel0aded1
User: Citrix

not working:401 and 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Youre re-implementing what is already done in the [LWP::Authen::Ntlm](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Authen::Ntlm) module (it calls internally the `Authen::NTLM`) . If you need/want your own implemtation, check the source code of `LWP::Authen::Ntlm` for some hints.

Comment: I would love to use  LWP::Authen::Ntlm but it's not working for me.

Comment: I have tried the code example in your code as followed and I still get 401 error code